# Jfreechart.draw() throws a Nullpointerexception

Tags: java, jfreechart

Issue: `chart.draw((Graphics2D) emffile.create(), new Rectangle(1500, 600))` throws a Nullpointerexception.

The bar chart can be generated. Please help to look into the issue.

Here my code:

```
CategoryDataset dataset = createDataset();
JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);

emffile = new EMFGraphics2D(
        new File("C:\\Workspace\\eclipse\\MSReoprt\\chart.emf"),
        new Dimension(1500, 600)
);
emffile.setDeviceIndependent(true);

emffile.setRenderingHint(
    RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, 
    RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY
);
emffile.setRenderingHint(
    RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_NORMALIZE
);
emffile.startExport();
chart.draw((Graphics2D) emffile.create(), new Rectangle(1500, 600));
emffile.endExport();
emffile.closeStream();
```

Category and jfreechart method:

```
private CategoryDataset createDataset()
{
    String series = "Availability";

    String category1 = "Portal";
    String category2 = "DB";

    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    dataset.addValue(100, series, category1);
    dataset.addValue(90, series, category2);
    return dataset;
}

public JFreeChart createChart(CategoryDataset dataset)
{
    FreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart
    (
        "Bar Chart Demo", //chart title
        "Category", //domain axis label
        "", //range axis label
        dataset, //data
        PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, //orientation
        true, //include legend
        true, //tooltips?
        false //URLs?
    );

    //set the background color for the chart...
    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

    //get a reference to the plot for further customisation...
    CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
    plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
    plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.gray);

    //set the range axis to display integers only...
    NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
    rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());

    //disable bar outlines...
    BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
    renderer.setDrawBarOutline(false);
    renderer.setMaximumBarWidth(0.5);
    renderer.setItemMargin(4);

    //set up gradient paints for series...
    GradientPaint gp0 = new GradientPaint(
      0.0f, 0.0f, Color.blue,
      0.0f, 0.0f, Color.MAGENTA
    );
    //GradientPaint gp1 = new GradientPaint(0.0f, 0.0f, Color.green,
    //0.0f, 0.0f, Color.lightGray);
    //GradientPaint gp2 = new GradientPaint(0.0f, 0.0f, Color.red,
    //0.0f, 0.0f, Color.lightGray);
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, gp0);
    //renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, gp1);
    //renderer.setSeriesPaint(2, gp2);

    CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
    domainAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(
        CategoryLabelPositions.createUpRotationLabelPositions(Math.PI / 6.0)
    );
    return chart;
}
```

Add stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.freehep.graphicsio.emf.EMFGraphics2D.writePen(EMFGraphics2D.java:679)
at org.freehep.graphicsio.emf.EMFGraphics2D.writeStroke(EMFGraphics2D.java:575)
at org.freehep.graphicsio.AbstractVectorGraphicsIO.setStroke(AbstractVectorGraphicsIO.java:981)
at org.jfree.chart.plot.Plot.drawOutline(Plot.java:1125)
at org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.AbstractCategoryItemRenderer.drawOutline(AbstractCategoryItemRenderer.java:717)
at org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot.draw(CategoryPlot.java:3684)
at org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart.draw(JFreeChart.java:1229)
at org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart.draw(JFreeChart.java:1112)
at chart.BarChartDemo.export(BarChartDemo.java:61)
at chart.BarChartDemo.test(BarChartDemo.java:39)
at chart.BarChartDemo.main(BarChartDemo.java:137)
```

Comment: Did you use an IDE for developing?

Comment: Do you have the exception stack trace?

Comment: What happens when you remove `.create()` from `chart.draw((Graphics2D) emffile.create(), new Rectangle(1500, 600));` ?

Comment: Since both dereferenced items on that line seem to be not null (unless you are running in some mocking context or similar...), the exception must come from somewhere deeper.  Please show the stacktrace.

Comment: add stack track thanks for the response

Comment: remove create(), give same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted [this answer](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117027#p178097) in the JFreeChart forum:

> This looks to me like a bug in the EMFGraphics2D class.  The null
>   pointer exception is happening at line 679:
>
> ```
> 678    private void writePen(BasicStroke stroke, Color color) throws IOException {
> 679        if (color.equals(penColor) && stroke.equals(getStroke()))
> ```
>
> I didn't run the code, but presumably either 'color' or 'stroke' is
>   null.  Since the code arrives here from line 575, it seems that
>   'color' is the null item (because 'stroke' isn't null, as it passed
>   the instance of test):
>
> ```
> 573    public void writeStroke(Stroke stroke) throws IOException {
> 574        if (stroke instanceof BasicStroke) {
> 575            writePen((BasicStroke) stroke, getColor());[/code]
> ```
>
> Now in all the Graphics2D implementations I've seen, getColor()
>   *never* returns null (I've written test cases to explore this behaviour).  But inspecting the EMFGraphics2D code, it seems as though
>   this is the default *plus* any call to setPaint() with a non-Color
>   argument will reset the colour to null.  I think that is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to analysis the issue. Is there any solution to fix the issue?

Comment: I didn't study all of the EMFGraphics2D code, but I would change that class to have a default color (by observation, Color.BLACK appears to be the usual default for Graphics2D instances) and then ensure that the color can never be set to null.  The get/setColor() methods are only there for backwards compatibility with the AWT Graphics class, Graphics2D uses get/setPaint().  When setting a paint that is not a Color (for example, a GradientPaint) I've observed that the 'color' attribute remains as it was (whereas EMFGraphics2D looks like it sets it to null).

Comment: Hi David, i used the latest jar files in the first time. Then i switched to use the earlier version, it resolved this issue. Thanks for the help.